# How To Persist Login Credentials for an API-driven Web App

Tags: php, api, zend-framework

I'm about to embark on developing a front-end that will let users login to a service and perform certain tasks. All of the tasks are being performed through a 3rd party's API using.

I'm doing this with PHP & Zend Framework.

My question: how does one persist the login credentials if every API call requires the login to be passed in the headers?

A user will be authenticated first through a /login controller and then will stay authenticated for their session.

Comment: aren't the api call's called from the server by zend ? i don't think i got you're questin right .

Comment: Yes, the API calls are invoked by Zend - but the users' credentials are required with each invocation. 

There needs to be some way of storing the users' credentials for each of the calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had simple suggestion

you can write your custom `Zend_auth_adapter` **and I'd like to make it singleton class** that can validate your login data over the API 
and save the result object inside the session object

```
class My_Auth_adapther implements Zend_Auth_Adapter_Interface {

  public static function getinstance($username , $password ){
      return $this->authenticate($username , $password ); 
  }
  private  function authenticate($username  , $password ){
    // make sure to check if the session has been already created  in order to save one api  request 
    // do your api call (login request ) her 
    // return false if its not valid 
    // or return stdobject that contain ($username , $password ) , for any post usage 
   }
}
```

and don't allow any further call to your api if that object doesn't exist (in other words == not logged in )

Comment: So basically, the authentication is stored in memory for as long as the users session is active?

Comment: session are usually stored as files in `/tmp` or what ever in php.ini  , since they are text only you can extend `Zend_session` to  store then in db , file based db ..etc  or  cache them using zendcache (MEMCACHE , APC .. )

Comment: Thanks - I'm pretty sure this is what I needed.